# How can I construct an mp4 with 6 equal audio channels (not 5p1) from an mp4 and a 6 channel wav

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, command-line, wav

OS is Ubuntu Linux.
I start with xxx.webm with picture and synced mono sound.
I construct the 6 channel xxx.wav which has the sound from xxx.webm moved to the 6 channels as appropriate.

`% ffmpeg -i xxx.webm -i xxx.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a yyy.mp4`

makes the synced yyy.mp4 with 6 audio channels, but the soundtrack is 5p1. Channel 4 is low-pass filtered. This is not what I want.

`% ffmpeg -i xxx.webm -i xxx.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -channel_layout 6.0 yyy.mp4`

is an improvement. Channel 4 is not low-pass filtered and it plays perfectly in ffplay and mplayer, but not VLC player.

It turns out there is no channel-layout in yyy.mp4, so there must be something wrong with my `-channel_layout 6.0`.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Share full log.